# apply ::-webkit-scrollbar to all elements except one

Tags: css, html, scroll

I have to remove all vertical and horizontal scrollbars from an html5 application, except for one div: a list of items. This div has a class .mydiv, and I'm trying to do this:

```
html {
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
}

.mydiv::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: auto;
}
```

Result: all scrollbars are gone, including the scrollbar of .mydiv. What am I doing wrong?

[image: all scrolls are gone]

Comment: have you tried to use the :not() ? you could try this :not(.mydiv)::-webkit-scrollbar{ width: 0; }

Answer (score 1):

you can use CSS Pseudo-classes in this case.
`.mydiv:not(:first)-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: auto;
}`

Comment: try this `:not(:first-child)` pseudo-class , if this does not work, review the code if is exactly class for scrolling..